# Is it possible to search multiple channels with one query?

Tags: javascript, api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to search multiple channels via the Channels.id parameter for videos with one query.
For example:

My request URL is: `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCSzAsgKDpNkch1eRA9w5nww%20%2B%20UCyCBf6asf89aQJaSXuAuTsg&q=Bitcoin&type=video&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`

The answer is:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "DCv8u79rz_Z5yPVlSxf2awnPWTQ",
  "regionCode": "DE",
  "pageInfo": {.
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 0
  },
  }, "items": []
}
```

Is it not possible with **YouTube Search API V3 in 2022** to search multiple Channel.id's for a topic with one request?

I have already tried several combining operators.
Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible in the way you're trying - when using multiple channels (*or multiple values in a field/parameter for that matter*), values are comma-separated, but, even with this fix to the request, the API does not bring any results.

[See demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22UCSzAsgKDpNkch1eRA9w5nww%2CUCyCBf6asf89aQJaSXuAuTsg%22%2C%22q%22%3A%22Bitcoin%22%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22DE%22%7D)

Instead, you should make one request per channel.

Search with channelId **`UCSzAsgKDpNkch1eRA9w5nww`** - see [demo # 1](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22UCSzAsgKDpNkch1eRA9w5nww%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22q%22%3A%22Bitcoin%22%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22DE%22%7D)

Search with channelId **`UCyCBf6asf89aQJaSXuAuTsg`** - see [demo # 2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22UCyCBf6asf89aQJaSXuAuTsg%22%2C%22q%22%3A%22Bitcoin%22%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22DE%22%7D)

---

If instead, you want to search channels that matches your criteria (*Bitcoin in region DE*), then see this [sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22q%22%3A%22Bitcoin%22%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22DE%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22channel%22%5D%7D)

Results (*summarized*):

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "MF1reS3I3oQvjOtYP2oZ8FI9sJ8",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "regionCode": "DE",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 19344,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "pBsNFEU4k7Fc5rWvL9z8woS_0ew",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UCwdYYyyX9V3u_b6URNpBh_w"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-05-24T15:48:35Z",
        "channelId": "UCwdYYyyX9V3u_b6URNpBh_w",
        "title": "Bitcoin verstehen",
        "description": "Was ist Bitcoin und wieso benötigen wir ihn? In diesem Podcast bringen wir neugierigen Einsteigern und auch Fortgeschrittenen ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/nz1XMTZCai2Op7clT386e3l9vFBb2eYKOexx8udRqDbmwDqkR10els3i-RYeH7ukSSoGWtSDp8A=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/nz1XMTZCai2Op7clT386e3l9vFBb2eYKOexx8udRqDbmwDqkR10els3i-RYeH7ukSSoGWtSDp8A=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/nz1XMTZCai2Op7clT386e3l9vFBb2eYKOexx8udRqDbmwDqkR10els3i-RYeH7ukSSoGWtSDp8A=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Bitcoin verstehen",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-05-24T15:48:35Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "j2amjttw_gCECoVnlJEB4Y5g41E",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UC61jC9ggxeGu8HJ9Q_TxOGg"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2013-09-06T02:12:33Z",
        "channelId": "UC61jC9ggxeGu8HJ9Q_TxOGg",
        "title": "BITCOIN",
        "description": "YouTube.com/c/BITC0IN https://Odysee.com/@BITCOIN:d77 https://Twitter.com/BITC0INALLCAPS https://zbd.gg/BITC0IN - Tip ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/WG8_95AszbGpSw8w2Qx1VWq_1Ko6-VIvfezMG_YRi330HpZMWQaroK1wMf--zBXKddg4TW2Wvg=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/WG8_95AszbGpSw8w2Qx1VWq_1Ko6-VIvfezMG_YRi330HpZMWQaroK1wMf--zBXKddg4TW2Wvg=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/WG8_95AszbGpSw8w2Qx1VWq_1Ko6-VIvfezMG_YRi330HpZMWQaroK1wMf--zBXKddg4TW2Wvg=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "BITCOIN",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "upcoming",
        "publishTime": "2013-09-06T02:12:33Z"
      }
    },
    [...]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hmm too bad, but thank you for the information! If I want to search a lot of channels for a lot of queries the approach would slow down the whole request...

Comment: @Manuel indeed. You can also consider use an unofficial API for search this data, like youtube-dl, for example (*AFAIK, this is for Python, thought*) or search if there is a way you can do this in javascript. If you want to do this *manually* - *i.e. by inspecting elements in the YouTube webpage* - and copy/pasting the desired data. Hope it helps and thanks for accept my answer.